# Way to extend router reducer?

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux

I am using `react-router-redux` (version 5.x.x) and want to know if there is any way to extend the router reducer to store some additional route information on the store. In my case I would like to store the location history (all the routes visited, params when first entering the site, etc.) in the state tree, and I would like to keep it in the router reducer if possible, versus creating a new reducer. Is this possible via the api? If so could someone point me at the correct docs as I have not been able to find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coming on a little late for this one but the only thing I could think of is this:

`reducers/index.js`:

```
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import extendedRouter from './extendedRouter';

const routersReducers = (state, action) => {
  let currentState = routerReducer(state, action);
  return extendedRouter(currentState, action);
};

export default combineReducers({
  router: routersReducers
});
```

`extendedRouter.js`:

```
function extendedRouter(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE":
            return {...state, anotherLocation: action.payload};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default extendedRouter;
```

That way, you create a new reducer and the `routerReducer` is the input state of your extend reducer. So it's a little tweak and not sure it's what you were looking for but hope it helped.